# Do i need another drill?

Tags: drill

I have an impact or power drill already, its a bit heavy so I am wondering if I need another drill which is light for the purpose of drilling screw in woodworks
I mainly use the power drill to drill a hole in the cement to put to tox

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  As long as your wife says it's okay, you should buy a new drill.  Not only will you be getting a new tool, you'll also be stimulating the economy.